# Jenkinsfile: Set environment variable based on other environment variable (Windows)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to create a Jenkinsfile with environment variables that are based on other environment variables. This fails to work as the %PATH% in the example below is not translated correctly.

What is the proper syntax to get this working?

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        ENVTEST1 = '$PATH;c:\\additional\\path'
        ENVTEST2 = '${PATH};c:\\additional\\path'
        ENVTEST3 = '$env.PATH;c:\\additional\\path'
        ENVTEST4 = '${env.PATH};c:\\additional\\path'
        ENVTEST5 = '%PATH%;c:\\additional\\path'
    }
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ('Build'){
            steps {
                bat 'SET' // print all env vars
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result in the buildlog is this:

```
ENVTEST1=$PATH;c:\additional\path
ENVTEST2=${PATH};c:\additional\path
ENVTEST3=$env.PATH;c:\additional\path
ENVTEST4=${env.PATH};c:\additional\path
ENVTEST5=%PATH%;c:\additional\path
```

None of the above options seem to be working.

Can someone tell me how to define an environment variable based on another environment variable please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use with double quotes when concatenating strings like that.

```
"My name is $first $last"
```

Otherwise you can use the "+" operator in this way:

```
'My name is ' + first + ' ' + last
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick, much appreciated Pastello!